# no new variables on left side of :=

Tags: variables, go, colon-equals

What's happening here?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    myArray  :=[...]int{12,14,26}  ;     
    fmt.Println(myArray)

    myArray  :=[...]int{11,12,14} //error pointing on this line 

    fmt.Println(myArray) ;

}
```

It throws an error that says

```
no new variables on left side of :=
```

What I was doing was re-assigning values to an already declared variable.

Comment: try `myArray,x = [...]int{11,12,14},3`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Remove the `colon :` from the second statement as you are assigning a new value to existing variable.

```
myArray = [...]int{11,12,14}
```

`colon :` is used when you perform the short declaration and assignment for the first time as you are doing in your first statement i.e. `myArray  :=[...]int{12,14,26}`.

Answer (score 33):

There are two types of assignment operators in go `:=` and `=`. They are semantically equivalent (with respect to assignment) but the first one is also a "short variable declaration" ( http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations ) which means that in the left we need to have at least a new variable declaration for it to be correct.

You can change the second to a simple assignment statement `:=` -> `=` or you can use a new variable if that's ok with your algorithm.

Comment: And `:=` can't be used with `_`? e.g. `_ := someFunc()`

Answer (score 11):

As a side note, **redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration**

Quoting from the Language specification:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank
>   variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

```
package main

import "fmt"


func main() {
    a, b := 1, 2
    c, b := 3, 4

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

Here is a very good example about redeclaration of variables in golang:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27919847/4418897

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've confused by a multi-variable short declaration, this explains why.

Answer (score 8):

```
myArray  :=[...]int{12,14,26}
```

As stated by the previous commenters,  **`:=`** is a type of short-hand and/or the short-form of variable **declaration**.

So in the statment above you are doing two things.

1. You are **declaring** your variable to be **myArray**.
2. You are **assigning** an array of integers to the **myArray** variable.

The second part of your code fails, because what you are doing here:

```
myArray  :=[...]int{11,12,14} //error pointing on this line
```

Is RE-declaring the **existing** variable myArray, which already contains integer values.

This works:

```
myArray = [...]int{11,12,14} // NO error will be produced by this line
```

Because, it is **assigning** the integer array to the existing ( pre-declared / initialized ) variable.