# Why there are two ways of declaring variables in Go, what's the difference and which to use?

Tags: variables, go, var

According to the Go reference there are two ways of declaring a variable

[Variable_declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) (in the format of `var count = 0` or `var count int`)
and
[Short_variable_declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) (in the format of `count := 0`)

I found it's very confusing to decide which one to use.

The differences I know (till now) are that:

- I can only using a `count := 0` format when in the scope of a function.
- `count := 0` can be *redeclared*  in a *multi-variable short declaration*.

But they do behave the same *as far as I know*. And in the reference it also [says](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

> It (the `count:=0`way) is **shorthand** for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types

My confusions are:

- If one is just the shorthand way of the other, why do they behave differently?
- In what concern does the author of Go make two ways of declaring a variable (why are they not merged into one way)? Just to confuse us?
- Is there any other aspect that I should keep my eyes open on when using them, in case I fall into a pit?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) make it clear that variables are declared. The `var` keyword is required, it is short and expresses what is done (at the file level everything excluding comments  has to start with a keyword, e.g. `package`, `import`, `const`, `type`, `var`, `func`). Like any other block, variable declarations can be grouped like this:

```
var (
    count int
    sum   float64
)
```

You can't do that with [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). Also you can use Variable declarations without specifying the initial value in which case each variable will have the zero value of its type. The Short variable declaration does not allow this, you have to specify the initial value.

One of Go's guiding design principle was to make the syntax clean. Many statements require or it is handy that they allow declaring local variables which will be only available in the body of the statement such as `for`, `if`, `switch` etc. To make the syntax cleaner and shorter, Short variable declaration is justified in these cases and it is unambigous what they do.

```
for idx, value := range array {
    // Do something with index and value
}

if num := runtime.NumCPU(); num > 1 {
    fmt.Println("Multicore CPU, cores:", num)
}
```

**Another difference: Redeclaration**

Quoting from the Language specification:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

This one is also handy. Suppose you want to do proper error handling, you can reuse an `err` variable because most likely you only need it to check if there were any errors during the last function call:

```
var name = "myfile.txt"

fi, err := os.Stat(name) // fi and err both first declared
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(name, fi.Size(), "bytes")

data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(name) // data is new but err already exists
                                   // so just a new value is assigned to err
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Do something with data
```

Comment: Too quick and much more detailed than mine. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why  they don't like us to using the `:=` format outside the function scope ? I can't find that could be harmful.

Comment: @armnotstrong At the file level everything (comments excluded) has to start with a keyword, e.g. `package`, `import`, `const`, `type` `var`, `func`.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html.          _______.    What does the variable relationship part mean from the go docs ? ______  "Grouping can also indicate relationships between items, such as the fact that a set of variables is protected by a mutex."

var (
    countLock   sync.Mutex
    inputCount  uint32
    outputCount uint32
    errorCount  uint32
)